# C# Terminate a Workflow Programatically from inside Code Activity WF 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

I have a **code Activity** hosted inside a **Windows Workflow Foundation Service**, I want to terminate the workflow based on some values I am checking from the database. I don't want to use the **Throw Exception** method, and I need to do it from inside the **"Code Activity"** Code, not from the **designer**. I am still a beginner in **WWF**, I tried the below method, which is creating a workflow application, and initializing it on the current instance of the code activity, but it didn't work. I need to capture the **parent workflow application** of the current activity instance first, then call the **Terminate** method.

```
   WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(this);
   wfApp.Terminate("The following workflow is terminating");
```

Thanks for your help on this

Answer (score 5):

To terminate gracefully, just use [TerminateWorkflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.terminateworkflow.aspx) as a child activity. This will invoke [WorkflowApplication.Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.completed.aspx) action.

```
public class CanceledActivity : NativeActivity
{
    private readonly TerminateWorkflow terminateWorkflow = new TerminateWorkflow
        {
            Reason = "Reason why I'm terminating!"
        };

    protected override void CacheMetadata(NativeActivityMetadata metadata)
    {
        metadata.AddImplementationChild(terminateWorkflow);
    }

    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        context.ScheduleActivity(terminateWorkflow);
    }
}
```

Or you can just throw an exception but this will invoke [WorkflowApplication.OnUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.workflowapplication.onunhandledexception.aspx) instead.

```
public class CanceledActivity : NativeActivity
{
    protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
    {
        throw new Exception("this will not gracefully terminate the workflow")
    }
}
```

There're a bunch of other ways of doing it, also depending on what you want to do and when you want to do it. Keep in mind that workflow will only terminate when it can, due to its asynchronous nature.

Comment: This sort of works, but I can't find a way to get the OutArguments from the activity that calls terminate. Also it sets the ActivityInstanceState to Faulted, whereas the ideal would be a solution that returns Closed (aka completed intentionally). Wishing wf4 had a proper f#*$*% end-node like in Visio.

Comment: @RJB I totally get what you're saying, and in a business manager perspective, drawing business rules, it makes totally sense BUT, if you're in such a situation, 90% of the time you should take a step back and rethink because terminate something in the middle feels unnatural in coding world. WF4 should be seen as a programming language through which you can draw algorithms, using activities. In a real language, if you terminate a method at the middle that's because you're just doing something (instead of computing something) and you'll return void anyway not needing output arguments.

Comment: That being said, if you need info back from the (half) workflow you have just executed, just write that info to somewhere, just like you would do in a void method. Looking at specific places of WF4 lib code, TerminateWorkflow is a well-known activity and when using it you're basically saying "*I known I'm breaking things up and messing with state and execution but please, just terminate workflow as soon as you can*". That's why it ends in Faulted state and that's why it's so difficult to give you output arguments back, just when you've broken workflow state at the middle of its execution.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the WorkflowApplication into the application context extensions which will then be available through the ActivityContext class.

```
// Add the application to it's own context
_workflowApplication.Extensions.Add(_workflowApplication);

// Access the application in your activity
var application = context.GetExtension<WorkflowApplication>();
application.BeginTerminate(new WorkflowException(error), null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and maybe my answer is dumb, I tried it and it gave me Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Should I pass the WorkflowApplication variable from outside the Activity as a parameter?

Comment: @HassanMokdad you need to add the application to it's extensions - a bit perverse but the simplest way i've found.  Answer has been updated.

Comment: That's not exactly the most correct way of doing it. You're attaching a constraint to the workflow for it to always have an *WorkflowApplication* extension. Use [TerminateWorkflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activities.statements.terminateworkflow.aspx).

Comment: @Jota I like your solution - composing the activities feels right.  I'll have to read up on child activities and try it out on my project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that in fact you have two activities in the one activity you currently want to use.
What you are asking for is not possible in flowcharts (i.e. Visio) either because one activity has only one exit what can be linked to a next activity (i.e. an end state), you'd need a decision block to be able to take a different route.

This is an example for what you try to translate into a flowchart:

```
public int CalculatePrice(string parameters)
{
    // Calculate result.
    var price = 5;

    // Are we done?
    if (!IsVATNeeded(price))
    {
        return price;
    }

    // Do more calculations.
    price = price * vat;

    return price;
}
```

Return from within body of a method is a code smell pointing to the need of rethinking the workflow. A healthy method has only one return.
I.e.

```
public int CalculatePrice(string parameters)
{
    var price = CalculatePriceWithoutVAT(parameters);

    if (IsVATNeeded(parameters))
    {
        price = ApplyVAT(price);
    }

    return price;
}
```

Now this second method is straightforward to translate into a flowchart/workflow.
[image]

If you have a different case please provide a sample flowchart or other diagram.
The rule of thumb is that if you can't draw a flowchart, a state machine or sequence diagram then it can't be implemented with Microsoft Workflow.

Note that it is possible to create create activities what are composed of other activities so you could embed the activities on diagram above into a single activity and hide the details. It would be the same like CalculatePrice method in code samples. The caller doesn't actually have to know how the price is calculated.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do:

`throw new System.Activities.Statements.WorkflowTerminatedException("reason string");`

from any where in your code and be done with it :)